# Issue related to Apache mod_rewrite and reverse proxy

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, webserver

I'm writing a new Apache configuration files that will do the below:

1. Accepting all the http requests from port 443 and `mywebsite.local` as ServerName
2. serving all the static content that located on the same server (html and js files) if the context `/static` comes after the URL `mywebsite.local/static`
3. For all the other requests, do a reverse proxy to a middleware server that located on a separate machine.

I wrote the below config file. However, all the requests are forwarded to the middleware server and ignoring the static content even if the requested URL contains `/static`

Note: the proxy and rewrite modules are enabled

snippet from the config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  mywebsite.local
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.200:9080/
    ProxyPassReverse /  http://192.168.1.200:9080/
    SSLEngine   on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/privkey.key
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/chain.pem
               RewriteEngine    on
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule static /static/index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [sf] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Your ProxyPass will catch all requests since you tell it to proxy on `/`.  Remove the proxy and rewrite lines.  Then do a RewriteRule with `[P]` option to proxy, where it will proxy all requests **except** when it starts with /static.